# pthreads again: why does the for-loop inside my thread function generate overflow?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I use 4 threads and my code puts 4 threads to work on 1/4 quarter of 10000 ints and finds all the primes in that quarter.
(i know its not a very smooth solution...)

```cpp
{
...
   for (int  o{my_data->thread_id*2500}; o <  (my_data->thread_id *2500) +2500; o++){
        if (prime(o) == true)
            ss << o << "\n"  ;
   }
...
}
```

Now when i try to use this for 100000 ints i get a overflow:

> threads.cpp:46:68: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 1103437824 * 25000 cannot be represented in type 'int'

and i dont understand it. Because shouldnt the number "1103437824" be 0,1,2 or 3?

My code:

````cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sstream>


#define NUM_THREADS 4

using namespace std;

bool prime(int n)
{   
    if (n == 1) { return false; };
    if ((n == 2) || (n == 3)) { return true; };
    if ((n % 2 == 0 ) || (n % 3 == 0)) { return false; };

    int sqrt_n{ 0 };

    sqrt_n = sqrt(n);
    
    int  i{ 5 };
    
    while (i <= sqrt_n) {
        
        if (n % i == 0) return false;
        
        i += 2;
    }
    
    return true;
}
struct thread_data {
   int thread_id;
   int  number;
};


void *worker(void *threadarg) {
   struct thread_data *my_data;
   my_data = (struct thread_data *) threadarg;

   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << "Thread ID : " << my_data->thread_id << "\n";
   for (int  o{my_data->thread_id*25000}; o <  (my_data->thread_id *25000) +25000; o++){
        if (prime(o) == true)
            ss << o << "\n"  ;
   }
   std::cout << ss.str ();
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main () {
        
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   struct thread_data t_d[NUM_THREADS];
   int rr;
   int i;

   for( i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ ) {
      t_d[i].thread_id = i;
         
      rr = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, worker, (void *)&t_d[i]);
      
      if (rr) {
         cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rr << endl;
         exit(-1);
      }
   }
    pthread_exit(NULL); 
}```
````

Comment: Works for me. Which compiler do you use? 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: @Ripi2: As pointed out in my answer, there is a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#In_software). Therefore, it may sometimes work and sometimes not.

Comment: BTW, once you hace defined a `struct thread_data {...}` type, you don't need to use `struct` word again to define an object of type `thread_data `.

Comment: solved it with pthread_join. thx for explaining it! @AndreasWenzel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to that error message, `my_data->thread_id` does not seem to have a value between `0` and `NUM_THREADS - 1`. It seems to have the value  `1103437824`. This is probably because `my_data` has become a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), due to a [race conditon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#In_software).

`my_data` points into the `t_d` array in the main thread. However, the lifetime of that object ends as soon as the main thread calls `pthread_exit`. Therefore, after that happens, the other threads' `my_data` pointer becomes dangling, which means it no longer points to a valid object. Dereferencing such a pointer causes undefined behavior.

The best solution would probably be that the main thread calls [`pthread_join`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3p.html) on all worker threads, before it returns from the function `main` or calls `pthread_exit`. That way, it is guaranteed that the lifetime of the main thread's `t_d` array exceeds the lifetime of the worker threads' `my_data` pointers, so that these pointers never become dangling.